# How to add CCLabelBMFont to the NSMutableArray

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I am creating my first game with cocos2D. And I have a problem looking for help.

I want to create some selected numbers and falling down randomly.

so this is what I did for the programe.

In my HelloWorldLayer.m

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CCSprite* background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"game.png"];
        background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:background z:0];

        operatorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        fallingNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] scheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(update:) forTarget:self interval:0.0 paused:NO];

        // Falling Number Font Type & Position

        fallingNumber = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"99" fntFile:@"MyHelveticaCondensed.fnt"];
        fallingNumber.anchorPoint=ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
        fallingNumber.position = ccp(160,180);
        [self addChild:fallingNumber z:3];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I have a method to generate the color for the numbers

```
-(void) colorFallingNumber{
    // FallingNumber random and color ------------- START CODE -------------
    do {
        fallNum = (arc4random() % 60) + 1;
    }
    while ( fallNum == 23 || fallNum == 29 || fallNum == 31 || fallNum == 35 || fallNum == 37 || fallNum == 41 || fallNum == 43|| fallNum == 44|| fallNum == 46|| fallNum == 47|| fallNum == 49 || fallNum == 52|| fallNum == 53 || fallNum == 55 || fallNum == 56 || fallNum == 58|| fallNum == 59);

    if (fallNum == 1 ||fallNum == 7 ||fallNum == 13 ||fallNum == 19 ||fallNum == 26 ||fallNum == 34 ||fallNum == 45 ||fallNum == 60) {
        fallingNumber.color = ccc3(217,101,75);
    }
    if (fallNum == 2 ||fallNum == 8 ||fallNum == 14 ||fallNum == 20 ||fallNum == 27 ||fallNum == 36 ||fallNum == 48) {
        fallingNumber.color = ccc3(79,166,134);
    }
    if (fallNum == 3 ||fallNum == 9 ||fallNum == 14 ||fallNum == 21 ||fallNum == 28 ||fallNum == 38 ||fallNum == 50) {
        fallingNumber.color = ccc3(217,148,15);
    }
    if (fallNum == 4 ||fallNum == 10 ||fallNum == 16 ||fallNum == 22 ||fallNum == 30 ||fallNum == 39 ||fallNum == 51) {
        fallingNumber.color = ccc3(209,75,217);
    }
    if (fallNum == 5 ||fallNum == 11 ||fallNum == 17 ||fallNum == 24 ||fallNum == 32 ||fallNum == 40 ||fallNum == 54) {
        fallingNumber.color = ccc3(75,149,217);
    }
    if (fallNum == 6 ||fallNum == 12 ||fallNum == 18 ||fallNum == 25 ||fallNum == 33 ||fallNum == 42 ||fallNum == 57) {
        fallingNumber.color = ccc3(217,75,32);
    }
}
```

And this is update method

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)dt{

    NSMutableArray* removeArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self colorFallingNumber];

    fallingNumber.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fallNum];

    NSString *fallingNumberName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fallNum];    ////// I think here is the problem 

    FallingNumber *newFallingNumber  = [[NSClassFromString(fallingNumberName) alloc] init];    ////// I think here is the problem 

    [newFallingNumber animateFallingNumber];
    newFallingNumber.scale = 1;
    //newFallingNumber.rotation = atan2(newFallingNumber.direction.x,newFallingNumber.direction.y) * 180.0 / M_PI;
    [fallingNumberArray addObject:newFallingNumber];
    [self addChild:newFallingNumber z:4.0];

    for(FallingNumber* fnumber in fallingNumberArray){
        fnumber.position = ccp(fnumber.position.x + fnumber.speed *
                               fnumber.direction.x ,fnumber.position.y + fnumber.speed * fnumber.direction.y);

        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(-80,-80,320+160,480+160), fnumber.position)){
            [self removeChild:fnumber cleanup:YES];
            [removeArray addObject:fnumber];
        }
    }

    // Operator animation ------------- START CODE -------------
    if(RANDOM_FLOAT() < 0.1 && [operatorArray count] < 15){

        NSString *operatorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"operator0%d.png", ((arc4random() % 4)+1)];
        Operator* newOperator = [Operator spriteWithFile:operatorName];
        [newOperator animateOperator];
        newOperator.scale = 1;
        newOperator.rotation = atan2(newOperator.direction.x,newOperator.direction.y) * 180.0 / M_PI;
        [operatorArray addObject:newOperator];
        [self addChild:newOperator z:2.0];
    }

    for(Operator* operator in operatorArray){
        operator.position = ccp(operator.position.x + operator.speed *
                                operator.direction.x ,operator.position.y + operator.speed * operator.direction.y);

        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(-80,-80,320+160,480+160), operator.position)){
            [self removeChild:operator cleanup:YES];
            [removeArray addObject:operator];
        }
    }    // Operator animation ------------- END CODE -------------

    [operatorArray removeObjectsInArray:removeArray];
    [removeArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Also, I have create FallingNumber CCSprite in other file

It contains about the property of direction, speed...etc

Well, the problem is I cannot add the falling number object to the array. And I found that one of the reason is I use CCLabelBMFont to create the falling number.

Because it is work if i use png file, it works in Operator.

Looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line,

```
FallingNumber *newFallingNumber  = [[NSClassFromString(fallingNumberName) alloc] init];
```

Is confusing to me.  It looks like you are trying to create an instance of the class FallingNumber, but by calling `NSClassFromString(fallingNumberName)` it looks like you are trying to instantiate a class that is literally called "16" or whatever the falling number happens to be.

From what I gather, it looks like you are just trying to pass the value of (fallingNumberName) to a new instance of the class FallingNumber.  In that case, I would make a custom initalizer in FallingNumber that takes the parameter, such as this:

```
in FallingNumber.h:

-(id) initWithString:(NSString*)name;
```

Then you instantiate the class by making the following call:

```
FallingNumber *newFallingNumber = [[FallingNumber alloc] initWithString:fallingNumberName];
```

Then you have a new instance of the FallingNumber class with the value of the string that you want.  Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Great! It works! But the random numbers cannot animate ! I will try to figure out ! thx  a lot ! :)